# Keep more than five versions of server less package to rollback to?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, rollback, aws-serverless

I am using the serverless framework to deploy a production system on AWS Lambda. I recently learned of the `serverless deploy list` and `serverless rollback --timestamp timestamp` commands, which seem very useful in case of emergency.

Is there a way to store/list more than five previous versions? I do not mind using extra storage, so I would prefer to keep many more versions (maybe 100?) available for rollback if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know serverless blocks the number of versions to 5, from this PR https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/4134/files

Did a quick test and you can backup the builds to other bucket and when you want to rollback you just need to move them again to serverless bucket then if you do list and rollback you can use them again.

This is actually an interesting case that could be easily done in a serverless plugin.

Comment: Thank you for this information! So if I have a deploy I'd like to be able to rollback to at any point, I can simply copy it from the serverless's s3 bucket into another, and whenever I want to rollback I copy it back to serverless's and it should show up on `sls deploy list` list?

Comment: Exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

what is the framework you are using to deploy?
I am using the serverless framework and this framework tried to hold all versions which I deployed by default.
That pushed me to use a special plugin for clearing the storage after every deploy because storage is limited (75 GB)

https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-prune-plugin/